# Get velocity in a specific direction from X and Y velocities

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've been trying to figure this out myself for a while using trig, but haven't been able to.

Given X and Y positions and velocities of an object, as well as the angle between the object and point, I want to find the object's velocity in the direction of a specific point. For example, if the object is passing by the point above or below it (moving across the X axis), the value would be low, whereas if it's moving directly towards the point, it would be equal to the object's actual velocity.

Here's a quick graphic I made since the description might be a little confusing.

[image]

I'm using this on a website so JavaScript code would be helpful, though I'm mainly asking about the math part of it which is why I posted this here.

Comment: In short: just some basic use of decomposing a vector into sines and cosines.

Comment: You can calculate the angle of movement by the law of cosines. Now, consider the angle between the direction and the given line to the stationary point. Can you find the relation between them?